# Looking for quick and simple blogging solution

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I'm looking for a really quick "plug in and play" style blogging software for php. It's to be used on a website that has already been design and deployed and it's really going to be used to add that extra bit of functionality. The things I really need it to do are:

- Manage blog posts (including some form of editor).
- Display blog posts on arbitrary webpages.
- Unobtrusive to implement.
- Nothing more.

This basically rules out wordpress/drupal. They are far to overburdened and I don't want to have to port the website to a word press theme. The blog is supposed to fit around the website not the other way round.

Yes Django would be perfect for this job however, the environment in which the website is hosted does not allow me to use it. If anyone knows of anything similar for php that would be helpful.

Does anyone know of anything like this? If not I will just write something basic but functional but it would at least save me a little time and effort.

Comment: I probably shouldn't, but I'm going to +1 this just because wordpress is such a god-awful spaghetti mess and yet people still (inexplicably) love it :)

Comment: How would your requirements rule out WP but not Django?

Answer (score 1):

[Serendipity](http://s9y.org/) is exactly that you want, in it's "embedded" installation